# What are the Lightning Round victory conditions in Civilization Revolution?

Tags: civilization-revolution

I know that the victory conditions are easier in the Civilization Revolution built-in scenario Lightning Round.
The civilopedia doesn't say what they are. What are the precise victory conditions for the Lightning Round?

**Cultural**
 *Normal:* Acquire 20 Wonders / Great Persons / converted cities, build United Nations wonder. 
 *Lightning Round:* Acquire 15. (Win immediately)

**Domination**
 *Normal:* Conquer and hold all capital cities.
 *Lightning Round:* Conquer 3 enemy capitals.

**Economic**
 *Normal:* Acquire 20,000 gold, build World Bank wonder. 
 *Lightning Round:* Acquire 10,000 gold. (Win immediately)

**Technological**
 *Normal:* Research Space Travel, build space ship, have it arrive safely
 *Lightning Round:* Acquire 24 technologies. (Win immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i discovered that if you READ the "Who's Winning?" screen instead of just passing by it as fast as possible that it answers the questions. :|

dom - 3 enemy capitals
tech - 24 techs
econ - 10k GP
cult - 15 things